# "Were going to" versus "were to" versus " were about to"

Tags: past-tense, future-constructions

I was wondering if there's a big difference between these three forms, which are refereeing to an event in the past.

> The works of many artists **were to be** auctioned off for the first time.

> The works of many artists **were going to be** auctioned off for the first time.

> The works of many artists **were about to be** auctioned off for the first time.

Comment: I reckon there's not a big difference between sentence 1 and 2, but the 3rd sentence is referring to a nearer future.

Comment: _Are going to be_ is more colloquial than _are to be_ - you would hear the first in conversation and read the second in a newspaper report or public announcement.

Comment: In the vast majority of likely contexts, *The works of many artists **would be** auctioned off for the first time* would mean exactly the same as examples #1 and #2. And #3 is only really any different because ***about*** conveys a stronger implication of ***soon***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Please notice that my examples are past sentences. It makes no difference?!